# Django AttributeError: object has no attribute 'assertContains'

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, testcase

I'm trying Django test fixtures from the official documentation, but my test class can't find assertContains.

```
from django.utils import unittest
from django.test import Client

class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_details(self):
        response = self.client.post('/register',
                                    {'username': '123',
                                     'password': '123',
                                    follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        self.assertContains(response, "Logout")
        self.assertNotContains(response, "Login")
```

Answer (score 5):

assertContains is a Django specific feature, not Python specific. Thus, make sure the test class is subclassed from TestCase in django.test, not TestCase in (python) unittest.

i.e.

```
from django.test import TestCase

    class SimpleTest(TestCase):
        self.assertContains(response, "Logout")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it (the first answer), In my case, i'm using django test_plus, and thats was the issue:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class BlogTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_blog(self):
    response = self.get('blog_detail', self.blog.slug)
```

Change the import to

```
from test_plus.test import TestCase
```